# R - head(b[, CAT]) kinda need help here to understand the logic

Tags: r, dataframe

Probably it will be a very simple question but I couldn't understand the logic behind this code and I need your help guys. 
I have a data frame which includes about ten columns (as doubles, factors, char). And I have also a vector like `CAT <- c(2:4, 7:10, 18, 24)`. 
lets call this data.frame `mydata`.
When I use a code like this, it contains some columns and also hide some of them;

```
head(mydata[, CAT])
```

When I put a `-` before `CAT`, it displays the other columns.

OK, I know the `head` function and the meaning of "-" but how it chooses the columns to display or hide? I couldn't understand the code's logic.
Thank you

Comment: The `CAT` is serving as a selector of column by number. Do `mydata[,c(2:4,7:10,18,24)]` and compare the result. it produce exactly the same as `mydata[,cat]`. `head` just  returns part of the `df`.

Comment: Read how `subsetting` works in r.

Comment: General subsetting is `df[row.index,colum.nindex]` . Call `head(mtcars)`, it gives you 11 columns. Then run `mtcars[,CAT]` , it will give you an error. Since there is no 18th and 24th columns in mtcars data. However, if you run `mtcars[,-CAT]`, then it means , take all possible columns but exclude the number 2,3,4,7,8,9,10,18 and 24. In this setting wou won't get an error even if there is no 18th and 24th columns. Since it is an excluding work now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is simple subsetting of data.

Here is a simpler example: `mydata[, c(2,3,4,7)]` will return the second, third, fourth and seventh column of your data. `head(mydata[, c(2,3,4,7)])` will return the first 6 rows of these columns.

If you use subsetting with negative integers then all rows except those integers will be returned: `mydata[, -c(2,3,4,7)]` will return every column except the second, third, fourth and seventh column.

Now when you plug in `CAT` instead of `c(2,3,4,7)` then something similar happens with all the values which are contained in `CAT`.

Answer (score 1):

It uses the values in `CAT` and displays the corresponding columns, i.e., 2,  3,  4,  7,  8,  9, 10, 18, 24.

So `head(mydata[, CAT])` gives you the first lines of a data.frame that is a subset of your original `mydata` (only contains columns specified in `CAT`).

The minus gives you all columns except the one you specified in `CAT`.

Please give a reproducible example if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer above, adding the `-` can be viewed as "not". In other words, placing the minus sign before `c(2:4, 7:10, 18, 24)`, means NOT columns 2:4, 7:10, 18, 24. So it returns the "other" columns.